# How do I convert this time format - 1480550400000+0000 in Y/m/d date format using php

Tags: php, timestamp, datetime-format

I am trying to convert this time `format - 1480550400000+0000` in `Y/m/d` date format using php `date('Y/m/d',1480550400000+0000)`; but its not working. How can I make it work?

Comment: It will wok properly.

Comment: @KinjalMistry nope, it will not work. date expect the second integer

Comment: @KrisRoofe it is integer. And I have also tried this one.

Comment: @Suchit nope, strtotime of this return false, and strtotime use string parameter

Comment: @SimplifysTeam What is the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved I just divided this with 1000.  $date = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp/1000); and it worked

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You timestamp has microseconds, so first remove it.

```
<?php
$timestamp = 1480550400000+0000;
$timestamp = intval($timestamp/1000);
$date = date("Y/m/d", $timestamp);
echo $date;
```

output: Check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/713818)**.

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
2016/12/01
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the second parameter should be time measured in the **number of seconds** since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). Looks like you have entered milliseconds instead.

[PHP date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

> **string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )**
>
> **timestamp**
>
> The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. In other words, it defaults to the value of time().

Try this:

```
echo date('Y/m/d',1480550400+0000); // 2016/11/30
```

Comment: Why you remove the 0000 before +

Comment: Because the time should be given in seconds. The one posted in the question is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dig_date= 1480550400000+0000;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdGis', $dig_date);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d G:i:s');
```

Comment: G:i:s is for time and date is in YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score -1):

@Symplifys try this:

```
<?php
    $date = date("Y-m-d", "1480550400000+0000");``
    echo $date;
?>
```

Remember to put timestamp in double quotes.

Try this code at http://phpfiddle.org/