# What kind of date format is this?

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I get this from a certain API:

`/Date(-27734400000+0000)/`

What format is it called? How can I convert it to a timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate in 2 parts:
- Unix timestamp - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522936/php-convert-negative-timestamp-to-date
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305826/what-does-0000-mean-in-the-context-of-a-date-returned-by-the-twitter-api

Comment: Seems to be a negative time stamp with mircoseconds. A related article can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583209/how-do-i-convert-this-time-format-14805504000000000-in-y-m-d-date-format-usin

Comment: That's a bug of that API. It seems to be using C# and that's the default JSON serialization of a .NET date object.

Comment: @apokryfos any legit way to deserialize it?

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason C# seems to serialize DateTime objects like that. Normally its of the format `/Date(Seconds since 01/01/1970)/` but the fact that this is negative (and so large) makes me suspect that there was an overflow somewhere. At any rate doing something like:

```
<?php
$str = "/Date(-27734400000+0000)/";
$strTime = substr($str,6,-2);
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(intval($strTime));
//You can also do some more sophisticated things to set the timezone based on the +xxxx part
print_r($date);
```

This one prints (at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e65641fa2aae0a3f49ce9c3f27457d7c6842b7b)

```
DateTime Object (
    [date] => 1091-02-17 16:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => US/Pacific
)
```

This makes no sense to me unless you're expecting some date in 1091. I think this is most likely an API bug you should inform the developers about.